# Why am I getting "User Already exists" message?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am a little bit confused with the code snip below.

When users attempt to sign up for training, the code checks to see if this user has already signed up for this class already.

If true, our defined error message raises an exception.

I have attempted using my account for testing purposes and I am continually getting the message that I have already signed up for class and this is not true.

What am I missing here?

```
 BEGIN
 Declare @Counter INT

    SELECT @Counter = COUNT(*) 
             FROM [Trainings]
             WHERE UserId = @userId AND CourseID = @cosId AND LocationID = @locid AND dateId = @dat
    IF @Counter > 0
     BEGIN
    --User has already signed up for this class. 
       RAISERROR ('You have already signed up for this training.',16,1)
       RETURN
      END
    ELSE
     BEGIN
    Declare @SeatsAvailable INT 
      --User has not already signed up for this class, then check to see if seat is still available
      SELECT @SeatsAvailable = (Select Seating_Capacity  - (Select count(*) from tblTrainings where courseId = @cosId) from Locations WHERE LocationId = @Locid)
     END
    END 

Protected Sub btnSAP_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnSAP.Click
    Dim userid = Session("userid")
    Dim Conn As SqlConnection
    Conn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Conn.Open()
    Try

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("signUp", Conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cosID", Request.QueryString("cosId"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", Request.QueryString("locid"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", Request.QueryString("iddate"))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
        Label1.Text = "Congratulations! You have been registered for this class. An email has been placed in your inbox with registration details. If email is not in your inbox within 10 minutes (usually, immediately), please look into your spam box."

    Catch ex As Exception

        'If the message failed at some point, let the user know
        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        Label1.Text = ex.Message

    End Try
    Conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: The code looks fine, so the only possibility is that the data in the table isn't what you think it is, or your front end application is running the code more than once.

Comment: @TabAlleman, thanks much for your response. 

I don't see where that could be possible on my front end code.

I have posted the code that invokes the SP for brevity.

Comment: You could use Profiler to rule out the possibility that the front end is doing anything unexpected.  You could also put a SELECT statement right before your RAISERROR statement to show what data in the table caused the @counter to be > 0

Comment: are you sending in the `userid` parameter ? i don't see it in your vb code.

Comment: @PupaRebbe, good gracious me!!

That was it!!!

Now, I am concerned because I expected to get an error that some param was needed but not supplied and I didn't get that.

What was more confusing was that I had the code, including the INSERT statement initially embedded in my front end app and this had the userid yet when I tested that one, I was getting the same already registered error.

Please allow me to give you proper credit for your work.

Thank you.

Thank you too Tab. Much appreciated